# Remove DOM element with JQuery after it has been Appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have tried numerous methods, but I am not able to remove the chat_box after I click away from it..

```
$(".attribute").click(function(){
                var chatVal = "edit " + $(this).data("attr") + " then press enter",     
                chatDiv = "<input type='text' name='chat_box' value='' id='chat_box' placeholder='" + chatVal + "'></input>";

                $(this).append(chatDiv);
            });

$(document).click(function(){

                //how to remove??

            });
```

Comment: just use  jquery `$('.chat_box').remove();`

Comment: use `.remove()`. `$("#chat_box").remove()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `$(".attribute")` ? If its a form element, you can listen for the blur event.

```
$(".attribute").on('blur',function() { $("#chatbox").remove(); });
```

Answer (score -1):

After you append an item to the DOM, you cannot immediately remote it as it needs time to update. Try wrapping your remove code in a setTimeout.

```
$(document).click(function(){
   setTimeout(function () { $('#chat_box').remove(); }, 10);
});
```

Besides that, everything looks fine. If this doesn't work, setup a jsfiddle to demonstrating the issue further.